# Liferay 6.1: Class not found with DynamicQuery

Tags: liferay, dynamicquery

I have a portlet project that needs to do some `Group` querying. I've not created the project but it was made with the Eclipse Liferay SDK plugin.

I've added a `DynamicQueryFactoryUtil.forClass(Group.class)` but it fails in runtime. It complains about not finding GroupImpl.class, which is implementation for interface Group. My project dependencies doesn't include portlet-impl (it contains GroupImpl.class).

I'm not sure if I should:

- include that jar into dependencies for compiling
- include that jar into portlet jar

Or I'm doing something wrong and querying groups would be available right out of the box.

PS: I'm pretty newbie in Liferay things...

PS2: **It's Liferay 6.1**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To enable Liferay to retrieve the right class, you need to provide a correct classloader to the initialization of your `DynamicQuery`, in this case the portal's classloader because that one has access to the model implementations:

```
 DynamicQueryFactoryUtil.forClass(Group.class, PortalClassLoaderUtil.getClassLoader())
```

Comment: Perfect. Worked like a charm. I need more Liferay training.